# How can I play an audio file using Raspberry Pi motion? Possible permissions issue?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, file-permissions, raspberry-pi2

Alright, so here's what I have:

I have a script, called **detect.sh**. This file is located in **/home/pi/detect/detect.sh**. It's permissions are: **-rxwrxwrxw 1 motion motion 66 Feb 19 10:20 /home/pi/detect/detect.sh**

This script, contains this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >> /home/pi/detect/detect_log.txt
python /home/pi/detect/detect.py
```

As you can see, this script executes my Python script.

My python script is located in **/home/pi/detect/detect.py**, as you can also see. My python script has the following permissions: **-rwxrwxrwx 1 motion motion 178 Feb 19 10:28 /home/pi/detect/detect.py**

My Python script contains the following code:

```
import os
import subprocess

text_file = open('/home/pi/Desktop/output.txt', 'w')
text_file.write('Test 1')
text_file.close()

os.system("sudo aplay /home/pi/detect/bark.wav")
```

When I start motion, using `sudo service motion restart`, nothing happens. I have, in the configuration file for motion, to

```
on_event_start sh /home/pi/detect/detect.sh
```

I know this is working. Because my detect_log.txt is created AND updated correctly, which means my script is running. But my python script is not. I do not hear a dog bark, nor is a .txt file created.

Also, my Python script runs when I run it using the standalone module, using Python. I hear a bark and the file is created.

Is this a permissions issue? What is going on? Could it be a permissions for Python issue? I am thoroughly confused, and have been searching for an answer for weeks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to accomplish, making your executable world-writable is never a good idea and a **serious security problem.** Try `chmod 755` instead perhaps.

Comment: Does `motion` have write permission to `/home/pi/Desktop`?

Comment: @tripleee does it need to have write permissions? I suppose you are right, because it can't create the text file otherwise.

Comment: @tripleee I will make sure to change the 777 after I've got this working. For now, I'm just trying to eliminate possible problems.

Comment: Your shell script probably doesn't inherit the environment you expect when it is run. Try replacing `python` in the script with `/usr/bin/env python`. Note that if this then works, your python will not work properly as it won't be able to find `sudo` or `aplay`.

Comment: A more traditional approach would be to write output to a shared directory. Start with e.g. `/tmp` and maybe explore other options once you get the basics working.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't been able to figure out how to execute a python script when motion starts. Instead, I just run a bash script on startup which creates a new .txt file. On start-up, I also have the python script of interest running a while loop; once the .txt file is created, it will exit the while loop and run the remainder of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Let's walk through this.

- When user pi executes the Python script directly, everything works fine.
- When user pi executes the shell script wrapper everything executes as it should. (I'm not sure why you are adding an extra layer of complexity, you can accomplish all of that within the Python script itself. 1st rule of Linux - K.I.S.S.,  3rd Zen of Python - Simple is better than complex)

This tells you there is nothing fundamentally wrong with the scripts themselves, they work. But you do have a permission error, just not where you are thinking. There is another script which you only passingly reference - the motion service script located at /etc/init.d/motion

In there you will find:

```
  restart)
    $0 restart-motion
    ;;
```

Which points to:

```
  restart-motion)
    if check_daemon_enabled ; then
        log_action_begin_msg "Restarting $NAME"
        if $0 stop && $0 start ; then
            log_action_end_msg 0
        else
            log_action_cont_msg "(failed)"
            RET=1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
```

Which references:

```
  start)
    if check_daemon_enabled ; then
        if ! [ -d /var/run/motion ]; then
                mkdir /var/run/motion
        fi
        chown motion:motion /var/run/motion

        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
if start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --exec $DAEMON -b --chuid motion ; then
            log_end_msg 0
        else
            log_end_msg 1
            RET=1
        fi
    fi
    ;;
```

Specifically, we are looking at:

```
if start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo --exec $DAEMON -b --chuid motion ; then
```

The start-stop-daemon '--chuid' flag changes to a user before starting the process, making that user the owner of the process. In this case the process owner is the 'motion' user. For future reference, another common method is to set the user in a variable in the application configuration file and '--chuid $'.

If you can get the service up, an easy way to get this info is to check the owner of the running process, but you should know where to look on your distro for the various service manager scripts (init/upstart/systemd) when you can't get the service up.

We know your scripts work when you execute them, we know that the motion user is able to execute your shell script, we know that the motion user has permission to execute the Python script. So there must be something in the Python script itself that is failing when executed.

The one thing that stands out:

```
os.system("sudo aplay /home/pi/detect/bark.wav")
```

As user motion, you are attempting to sudo this command. Does the motion user have sudo provileges?

```
$ sudo -n -l -U motion
User motion is not allowed to run sudo on nagiospi.
```

There is your permission problem.

So you have two approaches, give the motion user sudo privilege to play the audio file (bad, see below) OR find a way to play the file without sudo - I'd look for a Python library or user accessible utility if aplay requires root.

A few helpful suggestions:

- As slugonamission commented - making an executable world-writable is bad juju, I'll piggy back and say that world-read/write/executables probably shouldn't be in your home directory, add to that list files required by service scripts.
- Why are you using a shell script to execute a Python script to execute a shell command - pick a script platform and stick with it. Do not overcomplicate things, what we do is magical enough to the norms.
- Granting sudo privileges should be the absolute last thing you try. You should never run a daemon as root unless you absolutely, positively can not do it some other way - and even then I would start looking at a different solution altogether. This is an absolutely unbreakable rule when talking about anonymously accessible services.

Comment: P.S. slugonamission is also correct in using '/usr/bin/env python'. I would even go as far as say you should shebang it in the Python script itself and set the execute bit, that way you can call the Python from the wrapper shell script - most of the time.

However, I wouldn't do it in this particular case where all you need is the system Python Standard Libraries. As part of a service startup you do not want ambiguity.